# ¿Cómo puedo crear una Subcarpeta con el Path y el nombre del archivo para que no se dupliquen en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Buenas tengo una carpeta llamada files como aparece en la **var filePath**
mi pregunta es como le podria agregar el nombre del archivo que estoy subiendo a la ruta
para que me cree una Subcarpeta con el nombre del archivo que estoy subiendo y dentro
insertarle el archivo como por ejemplo (00-63-34.pdf).
Ya que ahora me crea una carpeta con este nombre **${NombreDelArchivoSubido}**
Si me pudieran Orientar o si hay alguna manera de hacerlo se los agradeceria.

```
    private static async Task<ActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        if (files.count > 0){
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var filePath = @".../../files/${NombreDelArchivoSubido}" + file.FileName;

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath + file.FileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo probar de la sigiente forma:
Sustutuye la linea de código:

```
 var filePath = @".../../files/${NombreDelArchivoSubido}" + file.FileName;
```

por la siguiente:

```
var filePath = @".../../files/" + file.FileName;
```